# Calling sub functions

Tags: javascript

This is a program to find the nth fibonacci number.

```
var fib = (function() {
    var save = [];
    var i = 0;

    return {
        "getNum": function(input) {
            this.input = input;

            if (input === 0) {
                console.log("Invalid input");
            }

            save[i] = i;
            save[i + 1] = i + 1;
            save[i + 2] = i + 1;
            i = 2;

            for (i >= 2; i < input; i = i + 1) {
                save[i + 1] = save[i] + save[i - 1];
            }

            console.log(save[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}());

fib.getNum(4);
```

My question is when I implement this problem in the following way, it doesn't work. I understand this is because I am not calling the sub-functions and only calling the main function. Is there a better pattern we can use that will keep the code organised and we won't have to make calls to so many functions?

```
var fib = (function() {
    var save = [];
    var i = 0;

    return {
        "getNum": function(input) {
            this.input = input;

            function valid() {
                if (input === 0) {
                    console.log("Invalid input");
                }
            }

            function config() {
                save[i] = i;
                save[i + 1] = i + 1;
                save[i + 2] = i + 1;
                i = 2;
            }

            function nthNum() {
                for (i >= 2; i < input; i = i + 1) {
                    save[i + 1] = save[i] + save[i - 1];
                }
                console.log(save[i - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}());

fib.getNum(4);
```

Comment: Is it correctly calulating the fibonacci series without refactoring the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of using `closure` to create private and public functions.If you see the below code only `_getNum` function is exposed.

```
var fib = (function() {
    var save = [];
    save[0] = 0;
    save[1] = 1;
    var i = 0;

    //This will validate the number
    // This function can be avoided and make _getNum do the same

    function _valid(input){
      console.log("Method Executing:_valid");
      input === 0 ? console.log('Invalid Input') : _nthNum(input); 
     }

    // Will calualte the series.
    // This is a private function
    function _nthNum(input) {
     console.log('Method Executing:_nthNum');
        for (i = 2; i<=input; i++) {
             save[i] = save[i-2] + save[i - 1];
         }
          console.log(save.pop());
    }

    // Private Function
    function _getNum(input){
            console.log("Method Executing :_getNum" ,input);
            _valid(input);
        }

    //Expose the private function
  return {
   getNum :_getNum      // Expose _getNum
  }
}());
fib.getNum(0);
fib.getNum(4);
fib.getNum(7);
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/qjgL5yo2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
var Fibonacci = (function() {
  var _Fibonacci = {
    // set initial values
    result: [0, 1, 1],
    input: 0,

    // main function
    find: function (number) {
      this.input = number;

      if (this.isValid()) {
        this.calculate();
        return this.result.pop();
      }

      return 'Invalid input';
    },

    // sub functions
    isValid: function () {
      return this.input != 0
    },

    calculate: function () {
      for (var i=2; i<this.input; i++) { // fix your code here
        this.result[i+1] = this.result[i] + this.result[i-1];
      }
    }
  };
  
  // return the main function
  return _Fibonacci.find.bind(_Fibonacci);
}());

console.log(
  Fibonacci(0),
  Fibonacci(4),
  Fibonacci(6)
);
```